# Vue Js Routing - Parent without path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router

Currently I am working on a project where I have two components with a `router-view`, `Auth` and `Dashboard`. These two components have different html strucutures but use the same base path in routing `path: ''`.

The routing file would look like:

```
{
  path: '/',
  component: Dashboard,
  children: [
    ...
  ],
  path: '/',
  component: Auth,
  children: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Ofcourse this will create complications since the paths are the same. Is there any way have a parent component without a path?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm doing something similar and I think it's the only way to do it.

Comment: @BlackCode I am sorry this has been a long time ago. I ended up changing the path for the `Auth` component to `/auth` (I think). Maybe you should make a new question to explain what you want, tag me in a comment or something.

Comment: Thanks! And don't worry Thomas. In the end I'm doing it like you but using navigation guards to redirect in case the user isn't logged in or the page requires auth :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new component that shows the `Dashboard` or `Auth` components conditionally, then set that as the component for the `'/'` path in the routes config.

Something like this:

```
<template>
  <auth v-if="isAuthenticating" />
  <dashboard v-else />
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes this would be an option. But do Vue developers consider this a "clean" solution for this problem?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the app. A considerable downside of this method is that you need a component for every combination of route + auth. In that sense I wouldn't consider it _clean_, but if you've only got a couple of routes you want to handle auth on, then this might be the most straightforward solution. I'm not sure what the design of your project is, but a more common approach to handling login without changing the route is to display the username/password form in a modal dialog when a login button is clicked.